# Cordova app cannot use internet after downloading via Play Store

Tags: android, cordova

Published a new app yesterday on Play Store been using/testing the app for months without a problem now but the version downloaded from the play store cannot access the internet (assumption). Never had this issue while running the app from Cordova CLI.

The app has a login page at launch which connects to a server - I can see in the app settings the app hasn't used any data at all and no errors are thrown in the app or the log cat (`adb logcat`).

What could be the problem? Details as follows;

Tested Devices

- HTC10 (Android 7.0)
- Google Pixel  (Android 7.1.2)

**Config.xml**

`<access origin="*" />`

**Manifest**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.PushHandlerActivity" />
<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.PushHandlerActivity" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

**CSP**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready; connect-src * ws: wss:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self' data: *">
```

**Auth Model**

```
 login: function(un, pw, onProgress, onSuccess, onAbort, onError) {
    var params = {
        username: un,
        password: pw,
    };

    var httpHeaders = {
        'X-CSRF-Token': app.token
    };

    app.authRemote.restClient.call(config.serverURL + '/' + config.serviceEndPoint + '/endpoint/login', JSON.stringify(params), {requestMethod: 'POST', requestDataType: 'application/json', httpHeaders: httpHeaders, responseDataType: 'json'},
        function _onProgress() {
            onProgress(app.authRemote.restClient);
        },
        function _onSuccess(result) {
            onSuccess(result);
        },
        function _onAbort() {
            onAbort();
        },
        function _onError(error) {
            onError(error);
        }
    );
},
```

**Auth Controller**

```
this.login = function(username, password, onSuccess, onError){
    app.authRemote.login(username, password,
        function _onProgress(restClient) {
            console.log('Sent = ' + restClient.bytesSent + ' | received = ' + restClient.bytesReceived);
        },
        function _onSuccess(data) {
            onSuccess(data);
        },
        function _onAbort() {
        },
        function _onError(error) {

            onError(error);
        }
    );
};
```

**Console from logcat**

```
 07-14 11:03:52.092 18738 18738 D SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/js/modules/system/controllers/auth-controller.js: Line 670 : Sent = 0 Bytes | received = 0 Bytes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found the answer to this finally...

Ajax requests were being blocked to `HTTPS` because I'm using a self-signed `SSL` certificate.

Although it is not recommended to do this (you should use a valid certificate for production), here is a quick way around;

- Install the `cordova-plugin-certificates` [plugin](https://github.com/hypery2k/cordova-certificate-plugin)
- `cordova.plugins.certificates.trustUnsecureCerts(true);` before making requests